# Oracle complex update statement

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table where data is as given below

[image]

My requirement is to update this table in such a way that, within a group (grouping will be done based on column A), if there is value in column B, same value should be updated to other rows in column B having null values within that group. If column B have null value for all the records within that group, then new sequence should be generated.Also I can't use pl/SQL block for this. I need to write a SQL query to perform this

My expected output is given below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use the `sequence_name.nextval` directly in your update statement, as the value will increase with every row, meaning that you would end up with different values in your b column for each a value.

The best way round that I can think of doing this is to first of all ensure every set of all-null b values has a single value in it, which you can do as follows:

```
merge into t1 tgt 
  using (select a, 
                b, 
                rid, 
                row_number() over (partition by a order by b) rn 
         from   (select a, 
                        b, 
                        rowid rid, 
                        max(b) over (partition by a) max_b 
                 from   t1) 
         where  max_b is null) src 
    on (tgt.rowid = src.rid and src.rn = 1) 
when matched then 
update set tgt.b = t1_seq.nextval;
```

This finds the rows which have all the b values as null for a given a, and then updates one of them to have the next sequence value.

Once you've done that, you can then go ahead and populate the null values based on the max b value for that group, like so:

```
update t1 
set    b = (select max(b) from t1 t2 where t1.a = t2.a) 
where  b is null;
```

See [this LiveSQL script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:43:9690582599002::NO:::&success_msg=QWN0aW9uIFByb2Nlc3NlZC4.%2FiiGcLv_inBBd9vzDCgUFC8vv6r1M0QsWJ803bTM8ZVi5_1jSvr8SEhbLCfdSJdZe7maJe10jA8BO4bQ5GSEBpA) for evidence that this works.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
update table t1
set B = (select nvl(max(b),sequence_name.nextval) from table where a=t1.a)
```

Ps: I couldn't test this. 
Indeed we can't use sequences in correlated subqueries... :(
One workaround is the use of merge :

```
merge into teste t1
using (select max(b) as m,a from teste group by a) t2
on (t1.a=t2.a)
when matched then update set b= nvl(t2.m,seq_teste.nextval);
```

One thing: that nextval will ALWAYS be consumed even when it won't be inserted. If you don't want that, you might need some pl/sql code.

Comment: I tried this one and I am getting an error as below 02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"